# Couchdb won't start

Tags: couchdb, vmware

I have 11gb free on my hard disk so I don't know why it's saying the disk is almost full. It was running the other day but has stopped working now. I am trying to use this to run ACRA. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on VMWare.

```
sudo couchdb restart
[sudo] password for zjulia: 

=INFO REPORT==== 20-Sep-2016::09:05:18 ===
    alarm_handler: {set,{{disk_almost_full,"/media/zjulia/CDROM"},[]}}

=INFO REPORT==== 20-Sep-2016::09:05:18 ===
    alarm_handler: {set,{{disk_almost_full,"/media/zjulia/Ubuntu"},[]}}
Apache CouchDB 1.6.0 (LogLevel=info) is starting.
{Failure to start Mochiweb: eaddrinuse
[error] [<0.113.0>] {error_report,<0.32.0>,
                     {<0.113.0>,crash_report,
                      [[{initial_call,
                         {mochiweb_socket_server,init,['Argument__1']}},
                        {pid,<0.113.0>},
                        {registered_name,[]},
                        {error_info,
                         {exit,eaddrinuse,
                          [{gen_server,init_it,6,
                            [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,344}]},
                           {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                            [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,240}]}]}},
                        {ancestors,
                         [couch_secondary_services,couch_server_sup,<0.33.0>]},
                        {messages,[]},
                        {links,[<0.92.0>]},
                        {dictionary,[]},
                        {trap_exit,true},
                        {status,running},
                        {heap_size,987},
                        {stack_size,27},
                        {reductions,641}],
                       []]}}
"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{bad_return,{{couch_app,start,[normal,["/etc/couchdb/default.ini","/etc/couchdb/local.ini"]]},{'EXIT',{{badmatch,{error,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,couch_secondary_services,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,httpd,eaddrinuse}}}}}},[{couch_server_sup,start_server,1,[{file,"couch_server_sup.erl"},{line,98}]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,273}]}]}}}}}},[{couch,start,0,[{file,"couch.erl"},{line,18}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

Comment: It looks like you already have something listening to that port (based on the error `Failure to start Mochiweb: eaddrinuse`)

Answer (score 1):

The "disk almost full" message is just a warning. The actual problem seems to be, that the port (5984 by default) is already in use ("eaddrinuse").

As a solution, you could either change CouchDB's port in /etc/couchdb/couch.ini or see which process is using port 5984 with `lsof -i :5984` and kill it.

Comment: Helped me too! In my case, there was somehow a docker process listening on that port. I killed it, but another one was spawned. So I changed the default port in the config file. :|